# Display Previous Year even it is disabled

Tags: jquery, datepicker

am using below code and working fine but i need to show the previous year too which is disabled

```js
const d = new Date();
let year = d.getFullYear();
let month = d.getMonth();

$(".input-monthpicker-freezelastyear").datepicker({
  format: "mm-yyyy",
  viewMode: "months",
  minViewMode: "months",
  startDate: new Date(year, month + 2),
  autoclose: true
});
```

here an adding 1 month from current month so i will display from nov+dec(2022) = jan(2023) .
but I need to display year 2022

please help me out

Comment: can you explain more , how you want to show suppose today date 28/11/2022 then ?

Comment: What about subtracting 10 instead of adding 2? ``startDate: new Date(year, month - 10),``